# Json_decode, file_get_contents var_dump returns NULL

Tags: php, json, nginx

I'm trying to get file contents from php-generated file with json data.

Json has been already checked by jsonlint.com site. It's valid.

```
$result = file_get_contents("url"); 
var_dump(json_decode($result,true));
```

Nginx does not displaying any errors.

Why it doesn't work?
Json generator is on external server.
When i pasted it on http://php.fnlist.com/php/json_decode website it was converted correctly.

Comment: `var_dump` the `$result` variable. Maybe you don't even get the content from the url.

Comment: `"url"` is it real or you passing a valid path of a file?

Comment: url is not real url its pasted for an example only

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: is file_get_contents returning NULL or is it really 0 (a.k.a. false)?

Comment: If you are not prepared to help us help you by answering these VERY RELEVANT questions, then all you are going to get are **guesses** and that wastes your time and ours.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last error message from the encode / decode...

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old question, may be this answer can help someone when see the same issue.

To handle this, make sure that:

1. `allow_url_fopen` is ON, check in `php.ini` file.
2. `url` is an valid url. To skip some issu about passing variable you can use `http_build_query`
3. return of json is valid. You can check the return is valid with [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)
4. `stream_context` is already setup so `file_get_contents` knows how to handle the request. 
   Even though we’re puting data over HTTPS, we need to use the `http context`. We set `method` to `PUT`, `Content-type` to `application/json`, `Accept` to `application/json`, `Connection` to `close`, and `Content-length` to the length of our JSON string. We’re PUTing this data over HTTP1.1 so we set the to `1.1`. We’re sending the JSON in the body of the request, so we set this in the content. And as we are using HTTPS, we need to configure the `ssl` settings.

   `$context = stream_context_create([
   'http' => [
       'method' => 'PUT',
       'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                   "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                   "Connection: close\r\n" .
                   "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
       'protocol_version' => 1.1,
       'content' => $json_data
   ],
   'ssl' => [
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false
   ]
   ]);`

Finally put the data by calling `file_get_contents` like this:

```
$getData = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$results = json_decode($getData, TRUE);
```

Hopely usefull, thanks.

Comment: You are using a var called `$json_data` - where is that coming from? I get an `undefined variable` error on that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be irrelevant but in my case this solved the problem. As seen in the picture, the "file_get_contents" needs "allow_url_fopen" in "PHP Selector" of CPanel to be turned on.[image]